# Multiple derivatives of an unknown function with change of variables

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

Possibly very simple chain rule application.

I have an unknown function $u(x)$, I make a change of variables $x=t^2/4$ where $dx/dt=t/2$

I want to find now $u''(t)$ and $u'(t)$ (in terms of $u''(x)$ and $u'(x)$

So far I have found the first derivative

$$\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{du}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{du}{dx}\frac t 2=u'(t)$$

However I am unsure how to apply chain rule to expand this to a second derivative. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that in short notation by chain rule and product rule

- $u_t=u_x\cdot x_t$ $$\implies \frac{du}{dt}=\frac{du}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$$
- $u_{tt}=(u_x\cdot x_t)_t=u_{xx}\cdot x_t^2+u_x\cdot x_{tt}$$$\implies \frac{d^2u}{dt^2}=\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\frac{du}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$$